# How to optimize large list aggregation

Tags: algorithm, loops, aggregation

I want to aggregation item score base on the rank
item will show on different list.and the list is the rank.
base on item location in different list get different score.then sum all the score

when the ranked_items list is huge.like 1000(list)*1000(items) then the loop will take too long.
Is there another solution for this problem

I have tried to optimize python.below is a simple version for easy understand

I hope there is another solution jump out of the box.use different way to solve this problem

```py
'''
there are some list of ranked items
each list has a,b,c,d on different rank
'''
ranked_items = [
  ['a','b','c','d'],
  ['b','c','a','d'],
  ['d','c','b','a']
]

'''
base on item location in the list
the first location has score 0.9
the second location has score 0.7
'''
base_score = {
  0:0.9,
  1:0.7,
  2:0.5,
  3:0.3
}

'''
sum total score of each item
eg: 'a' in the first list first location then score is 0.9
in the second list third location then score is 0.5
the third list last location then score is 0.3
add them all.'a' final score is 1.7
'''
final_score = {}
for single_rank in ranked_items:
  for idx,item in enumerate(single_rank):
    final_score[item] = final_score.get(item,0) + base_score[idx]

#sort by score
final_score_sorted = sorted(final_score.items(),key=lambda kv: kv[1],reverse=True)

print(final_score_sorted)

'''
output
[('b', 2.1), ('c', 1.9), ('a', 1.7), ('d', 1.5)]
'''
```

and the ranked_items could use other format
here is a 1D list format example

```py
ranked_items = [
    ('a',0),
    ('b',1),
    ('c',2),
    ('d',3),

    ('b',0),
    ('c',1),
    ('a',2),
    ('d',3),

    ('d',0),
    ('c',1),
    ('b',2),
    ('a',3)
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the ranked_items is provided as a 2D list, there's not much you can do to improve runtime complexity as you have to go through the 2D list at least once to read the data.

Meaning, the best conceivable complexity here would be O(N^2) in my humble opinion (given N = len([a,b,c,d])).

**For the 1D variant presented**,
you see, to produce any kind of result, it is a must to read the whole list at least once. Let's call the length of 1D list M. So, the best conceivable complexity would be O(M).

Note that this is not any improvement over the last approach as M = N^2, where N is the length of child lists in 2D representation. 
So, O(M) = O(N^2). You cannot do better than this.

Comment: ranked_item maybe can change to 1D list.but should still keep the rank and position.

Comment: please explain that. how can ranked_item be an 1D list? you can add the explanation as an edit to the question.

Comment: Hi.if out of the box.My goal is to aggregation the item score in different list different location.so the ranked_item can store any kinds of format to suit the requirements.

Comment: I've done some digging and like I said, the complexity cannot improved. However, You can easily go for a multithreaded approach with sharding to reduce actual computational time. 
For example, for the 1000*1000 sized array,  divide it up into 10 shards and assign them each to a thread with independent resultant tables. As soon as the threads are done, you can merge 10 resultant lists into one pretty fast and easily.

Comment: Yeah.thanks.I had consider about multithread.but this code used in API.so there are lots of requests per seconds.thus the server remain the same.so multithread will not have too much improve.

Comment: In that case, see if you can come up with some smart caching approach.